# what is the best way to find out the reason that Application crashed on startup?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, crash

i am now having the problem: when I start debuging, the app crashes directly and the debug process stops. I can not see any log or error message. I don't know what can I do in this situation?

I tried to add -v -v -v -v to adtional mtouch argument. but did not see anything print out while the app just stoped the debuging.

Is there a way to solve such problem?

best regards
Lin

Comment: look at the device logs in XCode

Comment: Also AppCenter.Crashes

Comment: @Jason Hi Jason, thank you for your comment. I am using VS for MAC, and i found the device logs here, but the error listed here are very difficult for me to understand. I searched using my project name as key word. and could see 2 errors related: 
1. Error (54) / SpringBoard(FrontBoard): Ignoring state for untracked process [application<ch.usz.jumpinE>:1125]*: <RBSProcessState: 0x2837f2d60; task: none>
2. Error (54) / SpringBoard(UserNotificationsServer): [ch.usz.jumpinE] Push registration with a nil environment was encountered, will not invalidate token. googled but no helpful info.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to catch unhandled exception like this

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
...


#region Error handling

        private void TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            var newExc = new Exception("TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException", e.Exception);
            LogUnhandledException(newExc);
        }

        private void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            var newExc = new Exception("CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException", e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
            LogUnhandledException(newExc);
        }

        internal static void LogUnhandledException(Exception exception)
        {
            try
            {
                const string errorFileName = "Fatal.log";
                var libraryPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources); // iOS: Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources
                var errorFilePath = Path.Combine(libraryPath, errorFileName);
                var errorMessage = string.Format("Time: {0}\r\nError: Unhandled Exception\r\n{1}",
                DateTime.Now, exception.ToString());
                File.WriteAllText(errorFilePath, errorMessage);
            }
            catch
            {
                // just suppress any error logging exceptions
            }
        }

        // If there is an unhandled exception, the exception information is diplayed 
        // on screen the next time the app is started (only in debug configuration)
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        private static void DisplayCrashReport()
        {
            const string errorFilename = "Fatal.log";
            var libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Resources);
            var errorFilePath = Path.Combine(libraryPath, errorFilename);

            if (!File.Exists(errorFilePath))
            {
                return;
            }

            var errorText = File.ReadAllText(errorFilePath);

            var alertView = new UIAlertView("Crash Report", errorText, null, "Close", "Clear") { UserInteractionEnabled = true };
            alertView.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (args.ButtonIndex != 0)
                {
                    File.Delete(errorFilePath);
                }
            };
            alertView.Show();
        }

        #endregion
```

Comment: thank you very much for the code. but it crashes before it. I set breakpoint on first line, but the App crashes and did not hit the breakpoint.

Comment: shared your AppDelegate.cs

Comment: should i only share FinishedLaunching?
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            ...

Comment: my app crash after launchscreen, it didnt enter into this code yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerOnUnobservedTaskException;

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            global::XamForms.Controls.iOS.Calendar.Init();
            global::ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();


            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
            DependencyService.Register<IJumpinNotificationService, JumpinNotificationService>();
            DependencyService.Register<IJumpinPublicKeyValidateService, JumpinPublicKeyValidateService>();

            LoadApplication(new App());

            InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh(TokenRefreshNotification);

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // iOS 10 or later
                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
                //Messaging.SharedInstance.RemoteMessageDelegate = this;
            }
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();

            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert, (approved, err) => {
                // Handle approval
            });

            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetNotificationSettings((settings) => {
                var alertsAllowed = (settings.AlertSetting == UNNotificationSetting.Enabled);
            });

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
```